# std::deque, references and 'pop'

Tags: c++, reference, queue, deque

I found the following code [here](https://github.com/egonSchiele/grokking_algorithms/blob/master/06_breadth-first_search/c%2B%2B11/01_breadth-first_search.cpp):

```
template <typename T>
//some code here

std::queue<T> search_queue; 
std::unordered_set<T> searched;

while (!search_queue.empty()) {
  T& person = search_queue.front(); // 'T& person' is what I'm particularly interested about.
  search_queue.pop();

  // some code here

  if (searched.find(person) == searched.end()) {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Since **std::queue** acts as a wrapper to the underlying container, which, in our case, is **std::deque** we find the following about **std::deque**'s [pop_front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front):

> Iterators and references to the erased element are invalidated.

Hence, **T& person** must be a mistake, because the element it refers to is erased immediately after the reference is created.

Is it so?

Thanks.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct and the code is not.

Comment: That your linked-to code ever worked is only due to Undefined Behavior possibly (and unreliably) being the behavior you wanted.

Comment: to fix it, make person not be a reference

Comment: Or to fix it, `pop()` only after you are done accessing `T& person`

Answer (score 2):

```
T& person = search_queue.front(); // 'T& person' is what I'm particularly interested about.
search_queue.pop();
```

yes, after `search_queue.pop()`, the reference `T& person` is no longer valid.

```
if (searched.find(person) == searched.end()) {
```

and this (and probably other code) becomes undefined behavior.\

A possible fix is

```
for (;!search_queue.empty(); search_queue.pop()) {
  T& person = search_queue.front(); // 'T& person' is what I'm particularly interested about.


  if (searched.find(person) == searched.end()) {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

which only differs if in that we don't `pop` until we exit the loop without `break`ing, and `search_queue` isn't poped until we iterate.

An alternative is

```
while (!search_queue.empty()) {
  T person = std::move(search_queue.front());
  search_queue.pop();


  if (searched.find(person) == searched.end()) {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

where we move the front element out into a local variable.